# count top 10 most occuring values in a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column in mysql table that has the the data type INT(11).

How can I search to get the top 10 most occurring values in this column?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
SELECT col, count(*)
    FROM tablethingie
    GROUP BY col
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Flagged my answer for delete (-: Is it possible to use count(col) rather than count(*) ? Hmm, and which is more efficient...

Comment: Ok, I guess you were the first to alter the mysql :-), I delete my thus and vote this one.

Comment: count(col) will count non-null values. Since col is what we group on, it's the same, anyway. count(*) is equivalent to count(1), but is generally recommended over the latter. count(*) is supposed to be the most efficient of all as long as it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Peter, mysql races! ;-) But what do you mean "alter"? The only thing I've altered when editing the answer was formatting, IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code

```
SELECT colname, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tablename
GROUP BY colname
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 3):

TOP is a keyword which is not supported in MySQL, it is in MSSQL though.

This following query should do what you want (untested, but the idea should become clear):

```
SELECT column, COUNT(*) AS matches 
FROM table 
GROUP BY column 
ORDER BY matches DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Up-voted to counter the down-vote; since, so far as I can tell, your answer is equally valid to all the others. I do wish that down-voters would *explain* their down-votes, though. That way we can learn something.

Comment: ricebowl, would that explain it? -  http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1831456/list - the answer was edited to mimic others after being downvoted ;-)

Comment: Indeed, because i saw an error in my answer, so i corrected it. This way there are provided correct answers and not non-working. Keeping high the quality of answers to a question.

Comment: Ben Fransen, I do not think you've done something severely wrong. It is more common to delete your answer and upvote the correct one, but your behaviour is by no means criminal ;-) It's just that it explains the downvote. (which was mine and I revoked it).

Comment: @hacker, that does explain, but a comment explaining the down-vote would've been faster. ...yeah; I'm maybe being lazy in my old age =)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT ColName, Count(1) AS occurances
    FROM
        table
    GROUP BY
        ColName
    ORDER BY
        occurances DESC
    LIMIT
        10
```