# MySQL query to select based on item with highest votes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple web app and when a user clicks favorite on an image the database stores a user_id and the image_id they were viewing, the table looks like this:

```
Favorites
---------------------
-user_id - image_id -
---------------------
-abc     - 123      -
-abc     - 456      -
-def     - 123      -
---------------------
```

I'm trying to find the top 10 favorite images (globally), that is the 10 images with the most favorites overall. The query simply needs to find the 10 image_id values that occur most frequently. So far I've tried a few things along the lines of

```
SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) FROM favourites GROUP BY image_id LIMIT 100 ORDER DESC
```

What would be the right query to accomplish this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831417/count-top-10-most-occuring-values-in-a-column-in-mysql?answertab=votes#tab-top hope its useful

Comment: Yes that does also cover it thanks! My search terms were a little wrong it seems, I wasn't finding what I needed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following query should do the trick, it is almost the same as your code, but the last bit is different:

```
select
    image_id,
    count(*)
from
    favourites
group by
    image_id
order by
    count(*) desc
limit 10
```

You might also want to have a read of [Q&A that I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) which covers off a lot of stuff like this in a great deal of depth.

Edit:

To answer one of the comments below, does using `count(*)` in the `order by` statement cause it to calculate again?

No.

```
mysql> select * from test2;
+------+-------+-------+
| id   | barry | third |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 | ccc   |  NULL |
| NULL | d     |     1 |
| NULL | d     |     2 |
| NULL | d     |     3 |
+------+-------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select barry, max(third) from test2;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test2 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)

mysql> explain select barry, max(third) from test2 order by barry;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test2 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> explain select barry, max(third) from test2 order by max(third);
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test2 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using temporary |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see from this that it stores the data in `temporary` and uses it from there.

Comment: Fantastic, that sorted it! Just waiting for the time limit to accept the answer. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @ScottHelme Great, but seriously, do yourself a favour and read that article. I dare say after reading it, you can come back here and answer a good few of the SQL questions that pop up :)

Comment: order by count(*) desc i'm concerned about this line, will mysql map it to the previous calculated one or will it calculate it twice ?

Comment: Sure thing, I will check it out over lunch.

Comment: @ra_htial something like `COUNT(*) [Count]` then `ORDER BY [Count]` do you mean?

Comment: i mean if we use `select count(*)` and then `order by count(*)` what will mysql do ? calculate this once and apply it or it will be calculated twice ?

Comment: Interesting, but I dare say that it won't make a difference. Let me have a quick look and post back.

Comment: @ra_htial There we go, looks like it doesn't calculate it over, it uses temp storage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  image_id, count(image_id)
FROM Favorites
GROUP BY image_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 10
```