# Print the most watched videos for each category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have two tables

```
video(id,macro_categoria,categoria,titolo)
```

and

```
video_logs(id,idvideo,logs)
```

(stores how many times a vid has been watched).
The relationship is one with many `id=>idvideo` 
I want a result like this:

```
  macro_categoria:one {
          [1]=> video 1 details
          [2]=> video 2 details
          [3]=> video 3 details
          [4]=> video 4 details
        }
  macro_categoria:two {
          [1]=> video 1 details
          [2]=> video 2 details
          [3]=> video 3 details
          [4]=> video 4 details
        }
```

The array above prints the four most watched videos for each macro_categoria.The number of how many times a video has been watched is taken from logs of table video_logs.Currently I am at this point and I am stuck:

```
SELECT c.macro_categoria,c.id, Count((v.id)) as Views
 FROM video c,video_log v
 WHERE c.id = v.idvideo
 GROUP BY c.id 
 ORDER BY Views DESC LIMIT 4
```

This echos:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [macro_categoria] => macro2
            [id] => 11
            [Views] => 47
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [macro_categoria] => macro1
        [id] => 12
        [Views] => 23
    )
```

Comment: whats the question here?

Comment: @rtfm print the four most watched videos of each macro_category

Comment: query a join, some aggrigation, no need t do the counting in php

Comment: the join only gets me the videos that have been watched...okay but how do I print it in that way and only 4 most watched vids @rtfm

Comment: you will need a count, a group by, order by and limit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count top 10 most occuring values in a column in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831417/count-top-10-most-occuring-values-in-a-column-in-mysql)

Comment: @rtfm how is it a duplicate when I am trying to get items from another table?I need to group them and then select it.Just because it has limit that does not solve my problem

Comment: @rtfm if you dont want to help,dont ruin the opportunity for others

Comment: how am i ruining the opportunity for others ?!?!!?!

Comment: you a mod now? because only they know who voted. i could prove it was was not me if you like by giving you another, would you like that?

Comment: rtfm is right. This is a question best solved by you learning how to write an sql query. Operators involved in your solution are JOIN (to get data from both tables), GROUP BY (to operate on records that have something in common), and COUNT. All very fundamental query tools that you would be well served to take the time to understand.

Comment: @sorak I have done all that I could,now I am asking for help\

Comment: @sorak I am at work I can't talk,would love to but..PLease take only 10 min to help me with an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query to select each category with counts:

```
SELECT videos.id, cats.macro_categoria, videos.titolo, IFNULL(views.cnt, 0) AS cnt 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT macro_categoria FROM `video`) cats 
JOIN (SELECT id, macro_categoria, titolo FROM video) videos ON videos.macro_categoria = cats.macro_categoria 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT idvideo, COUNT(idvideo) as cnt FROM video_log GROUP BY idvideo) `views` ON `views`.idvideo = videos.id 
ORDER BY cats.macro_categoria, cnt DESC
```

Here, we're starting from the list of categories, (INNER) joining videos to these categories, and then LEFT joining view counts, so that we still have NULL results so you can know where there are no views. Then sort by category and views, descending.

If you want to get the four top members of each category in PHP you could use logic like the following (a little pseudocodey):

```
$result = DB::query($sql);
$byCategory = [];
while ($row = DB::fetchAssoc($result)) {
    // Create array to hold category
    if (!isset($category[$result['macro_categoria']))
        $category[$result['macro_categoria'] = [];

    // Store record
    $byCategory[$result['macro_categoria']][] = $result;
}

// Trim results per category
foreach ($byCategory AS $cat=>$data)
    $byCategory[$cat] = array_slice($data, 0, 4);
```

The `array_slice` grabs the four first elements of each category. This will return the top values as long as the resultset is sorted appropriately from the server.